# @Named providers with same return types end up giving java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Duplicate

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, libgdx, dagger

Here is the issue,

I am working on a LibGDX project where i have different modules for different platforms.

This is how my android module looks like:

```
@Module(
    includes = {BaseModule.class, NetModule.class},
    injects = {DummyProjectActivity.class, DummyProject.class},
    overrides = true)
public class DummyProjectAndroidModule {

    ...

    @Provides @Singleton @Named("DummyOne")
    DummyInterface provideDummyOne() {
        return new DummyOne();
    }

    @Provides @Singleton @Named("DummyTwo")
    DummyInterface provideDummyTwo() {
        return new DummyTwo();
    }

    @Provides @Singleton @Named("DummyConsumer")
    DummyConsumer provideDummyConsumer(@Named("DummyOne") DummyInterface dummyOne,
                                    @Named("DummyTwo") DummyInterface dummyTwo) {
        return new DummyConsumer(dummyOne, dummyTwo);
    }
}
```

.. and here how my desktop module looks like:

```
@Module(
    includes = {BaseModule.class, NetModule.class},
    injects = {DummyProjectDesktop.class, DummyProject.class},
    overrides = true)
public class DummyProjectDesktopModule {
```

well rest is pretty much the same. Yet while i'm building the project for Desktop everything goes nice and dandy where on Android side, i get this error which leaves me flabbergasted still.

```
Process: net.alicanhasirci.mobile.DummyProject.android, PID: 4603
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.alicanhasirci.mobile.DummyProject.android/net.alicanhasirci.mobile.DummyProject.android.DummyProjectActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Duplicate:
    net.alicanhasirci.mobile.android.image.DummyInterface net.alicanhasirci.mobile.DummyProject.android.DummyProjectAndroidModule.provideDummyOne()
    net.alicanhasirci.mobile.android.image.DummyInterface net.alicanhasirci.mobile.DummyProject.android.DummyProjectAndroidModule.provideDummyTwo()
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2365)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5272)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Duplicate:
    net.alicanhasirci.mobile.android.image.DummyInterface net.alicanhasirci.mobile.DummyProject.android.DummyProjectAndroidModule.provideDummyOne()
    net.alicanhasirci.mobile.android.image.DummyInterface net.alicanhasirci.mobile.DummyProject.android.DummyProjectAndroidModule.provideDummyTwo()
            at dagger.internal.UniqueMap.put(UniqueMap.java:29)
            at dagger.internal.plugins.reflect.ReflectiveModuleAdapter.handleBindings(ReflectiveModuleAdapter.java:104)
            at dagger.internal.plugins.reflect.ReflectiveModuleAdapter.getBindings(ReflectiveModuleAdapter.java:89)
            at dagger.ObjectGraph$DaggerObjectGraph.makeGraph(ObjectGraph.java:174)
            at dagger.ObjectGraph$DaggerObjectGraph.access$000(ObjectGraph.java:132)
            at dagger.ObjectGraph.create(ObjectGraph.java:129)
            at net.alicanhasirci.mobile.DummyProject.android.DummyProjectActivity.onCreate(DummyProjectActivity.java:137)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5977)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
```

now a quick glimpse at dagger source code and i can see that qualifier annotations are gathered by reflection and getting used as prefixes for binding names which will be later used as keys in UniqueMap. My problem seem to occur somewhere around this area where my qualifier does not  get processed somehow, yet my desktop build works without a problem...

Here are some more additional:

```
ObjectGraph objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(new DummyProjectAndroidModule());
    objectGraph.inject(this);
    dp = objectGraph.get(DummyProject.class);
```

is how i get my `DummyProject` object, which has a field injection of `DummyConsumer`. As such:

```
@Inject @Named("DummyConsumer") DummyConsumer consumer;
```

I have changed the return types to concrete classes as a workaround but nobody likes a workaround cause we all know that they haunt you till the end.

Comment: Please upgrade to a more recent release of Dagger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally figured out the reason why this problem occurs. It is Proguard. Unless you say specify otherwise in proguard config file, it will obfuscate the generated code while pruning annotations and what not which will cause unexpected results.

Only way to make Proguard and Dagger coexist is to basically give up on most of the obfuscation or switch to Dagger2, as Jake Wharton said on https://github.com/square/dagger/issues/202. I am using proguard only to avoid hitting 65k limit so making the necessary configs to avoid obfuscation solved my problem.